# How to add backspace on string in php

Tags: php

I have a string php:

```
$text = "search";
$text = "&nbsp;".$text."&nbsp"; // OR $text = " ".$text." ";
```

When I echo $text is result error, How to add backspace on string

Comment: nbsp is a non breaking space, not a backspace...

Comment: I just tested your code and get no error ! http://codepad.org/hZwti3GE

Answer (score 0):

You have missed the last semicolon in second line
you have `&nbsp` it should be `&nbsp;`

```
$text = "search";
$text = "&nbsp;".$text."&nbsp;"; // OR $text = " ".$text." ";
```